# React Fetch API Cannot Render Image

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am using a Fetch API to return data from an API I built. Here is what my code looks like:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'; 
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import FeedbackNav from './feedbacknav'; 
import UserContext from "../context/UserContext"; 
import Landing from './Landing'; 
import useFetch from './usefetch';

const ReviewInfo = () => {
    const { userData } = useContext(UserContext);
    const { id } = useParams();  
    const {data: review, error, isPending} = useFetch(`http://localhost:5000/reviews/reviews?_id=` + id);

    return (
        <div>
            {userData.user ? (
        <div>
            <div>
                {/* <FeedbackNav /> */}
            </div>
            <p className='testing12345'>This is a test {id} </p>
            { isPending && <div className='testing12345'>Loading...</div> }
            { error && <div>{ error }</div> }
            {review && (
                <div>
                    <img alt='soempty' src={review[0].userImage} className="dotdat"></img>
                    <p className='testing12345'>{review[0].firstName} {review[0].lastName}</p>
                    <p className='testing12345'>{review[0].city}</p>
                    <p className='testing12345'>{review[0].projectName}</p>
                    <p className='testing12345'>{review[0].review}</p>
                </div>
            )
            }
    </div>
    ) : (
        <div>
            <Landing /> 
        </div>
    )}
    </div>
    )
}

export default ReviewInfo;
```

When I save the code, the userImage does not render to the browser, while the other data I am trying to fetch from the API render successfully (firstName, lastName, city, projectName, review). I have tried a few different things, but I am stuck. What might I be doing wrong?

From dev tools:
[image: image from dev tools]

Appreciate the help!

Comment: What is the URL of the page you are on? You do not have a leading slash on the image URL, this means it will replace the last part of the path with the partial URL provided i.e. if your are at `localhost/reviews/1` it would be looking for `localhost/reviews/uploads/...`. Is this what you intended?

Comment: & after checking the full image path, you need to have some server that serve the images, because the database job is to serve data not assets, so keep an eye on that too

Comment: the full image path that I am on is: http://localhost:3000/reviewinfo/602045d27c3eb0eef056022b
602045d27c3eb0eef056022b is the id that I am passing as a parameter from a previous page

Comment: And I see in the network that it is trying to call the following url to fetch the image - GET /reviewinfo/uploads/1612579406646-15390717_10209981974419262_8253015868667366792_n.jpg 404 0.391 ms - 
224